# Automatically replace cell value with another cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a database table with two columns, `business names` and `branches`.

I want to substitute cells that contain the the branches with their business name

Example :

```
Business name     Branch
-------------------------------------------------
MacDonald         MacDonald Silver Canoe Way
MacDonald         MacDonald Loch Ness Road
Pizza hut         Pizza hut Mistletoe Lane
```

I have copied the branch column from a list that always has the business name and the branch together in the same cell, they are not separated

What do I need?

I want to replace "Branch" name with "Business" given that I want the formatting for "Branch" to be transferred, for example I want MacDonald to have

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this with the CONCATENATE function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d.

So the formula would be `=CONCATENATE(A1, B1)` for the first two cells where A1=MacDonald and B1 =  Silver Canoe Way